# Redirect to an external URL and routes.rb config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to redirect to a specific URL with current controller params.
It would be nice if I could do that with a named route.

I actually have a controller containing :

```
redirect_to another_host_path(params.except(:action, :controller))
```

And a `config/routes.rb` containing :

```
match 'another/host', to: redirect { |params, request| "http://www.foobar.com/login?#{request.query_string}" }, via: :get
```

But it doesn't redirect me to `localhost` instead of `foobar.com` host.

Note : That URL corresponds to a website of the same controlled domain. The current app is just a stateless API and has no HTML rendering middleware. I need to redirect to a JS app located somewhere else on the same domain. More, the informations present in query string are public domain.

Thank you,

M.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, use `_path` suffix instead of `_url` to specify the redirect target:

```
redirect_to another_host_path(params.except(:action, :controller))
```

Also make sure you're not facing a problem by redirecting to a URL based on things provided by the user. I think the `brakeman` gem would highlight this as a potential security vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even with _path it does not redirect_to the foobar.com URL. Still localhost... :(

Comment: You want the URL of a completely different site, but passing the same query string that your controller received? If so, that really does sound like it open you up to some security problems, if a user (or man in the middle between your legit user and your server) got creative with that query string.

Comment: That URL corresponds to a website of the same controlled domain. The current app is just a stateless API and has no HTML rendering middleware. I need to redirect to a JS app located somewhere else on the same domain. More, the informations present in query string are public domain.